# Google maps API not loading properly

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to use `google maps JS API v3` in one of my projects everything was working fine until day before yesterday, then suddenly it stopped working when i tried to debug using console it showed that the `url` for loading map script `main.js` was failing

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map-canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={API_KEY}&sensor=true">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 8
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have used a real API key in place of {API_KEY}

How can I achieve my objective?

Comment: Try loading map without `key` parameter and check if any error occurs.

Comment: You are using the "experimental" version, perhaps a new release is coming out (or just came out).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I pasted your code into a file named test.html, inserted a valid api key and tested the following browsers in MAC OS X 10.9:

- Safari
- Chrome
- Firefox

It works in all these browser without any error. Please check the following:

- Validation period of your api key
- invisible characters

Comment: I just checked the validation period its same as the time I generated it, deleted that key and created a new one, its working now thanks.